# Ошибка при группировке и последующей выборке

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, select, order

Вот код:

```
select distinct maker, type from product
order by maker, 
                case type
                when 'PC' then 1
                when 'Laptop' then 2
                else 3
                end
```

Ошибка: Элементы ORDER BY должны входить в список выбора, если указывается SELECT DISTINCT.

Так элемент `type` находится в select, почему же возникает ошибка?
И кстати: зачем вообще введено данное требование? - Допустим я хочу каким-нибудь таким образом отсортировать, и затем произвести какую-либо уникальную выборку.

Comment: Какую именно СУБД используете? Добавьте метку.

Comment: Такого рода код в MySQL работает без проблем

Comment: T-Sql используется

Answer (score 0):

> зачем вообще введено данное требование?

Для того, чтобы не было необходимости делать SQL-сервер умнее пользователя.

Суть в том, что сначала отрабатывает группировка, и лишь потом сортировка.

Когда обработка доходит до сортировки, в выборке остаются только столбцы, входящие в список выборки, сортировать по другим уже невозможно.

PS о том, что distinct - группировка:

```
select distinct maker, type from product
```

эквивалентно

```
select maker, type from product group by maker, type
```

Comment: окей, значит сортировка выполняется в последнюю очередь. Тогда что не так в запросе?

Comment: Странно, на MS-SQL 2005 такие запросы, вроде, работали. Точно можно заменить distinct на group by, и должно выполниться.

Comment: Возможно, MS при реализации T-SQL решили, что нужно строго следовать стандарту и упростили проверку.